# Can we have narrow parent with full-width child that does not rely on body {overflow-x: hidden}

Tags: css, layout, overflow

All solutions are similar and all rely on `body: {overflow-x: hidden}` which perhaps is not best practice or is it ?

Here is an example that you can play with https://codepen.io/giorgosk/pen/vYrqOeG?editors=1100

At least in this case part of the full width container (text) is hidden to the left when vertical scrollbars are present.  Might want to change the `.main {min-height:}` to see what I mean.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* solution without this */
}

.main {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 3000px;
}

.inside {
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  margin-right: calc(50% - 50vw);
}

.full-width2 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.full-width3 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>play with .main {min-height}</div>
  <div>if .main content height is within viewport we are OK</div>
  <div>if .main content height overflows full width div miscalculates the scrollbar (I believe)</div>
  <div class="inside full-width3">full width container</div>
  more content below full width
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach – albeit, this emulates the situation of having a child larger than its parent – is to use CSS Grid layout, as follows; with explanatory comments in the CSS:

```css
/* simple reset to have all browsers use the same sizing algorithm,
   border-box, to ensure that padding and border-widths are included
   in the declared size of elements; setting the base font-size
   and font-family to 16px system-ui, and removing margin/padding
   from to unset browser defaults: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* instead of using <div class="main"> I chose to use a - semantic - <main>
   element: */ 
main {
  /* because we the desired background-color of the <main> element - written
     below in hsl() form - would include the gutters at either side of the
     screen I've opted to use a background-image (using the linear-gradient
     function) with color-stops to match the grid-column-tracks: */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      /* the direction in which the gradient runs: */
      90deg,
      /* the transparent colour starts at 0 and continues until 5% of the
         element's width: */
      transparent 0 5%,
      /* the grey colour starts 5% of the element's width and continues until
         95%: */
      hsl(0deg 0% 90% / 1) 5% 95%,
      /* at which point the transparent colour resumes: */
      transparent 95%
    );
  /* specifying CSS grid for the layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting a 1em gap between adjacent elements: */
  gap: 1em;
  /* sizing the rows of the grid to take the smallest space possible that will
     allow the content to fit: */
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  /* we define three columns:
       5%: one column track of 5%, equal to 5% of the element's width:
       1fr: specifies that this column should take one fraction of the
       available width remaining after the absolute-sized (the 5%) columns
       are calculated: */
  grid-template-columns: 5% 1fr 5%;
  /* using CSS logical properties to determine the minimum-size of the element
     along the block-axis (in European languages, and their derivatives, this
     is equivalent to 'height'), and specifying 100 dynamic viewport units (so
     this should occupy 100% of the block-axis of the <body> regardless of
     whether browser chrome is showing (address-bar, scroll-bars, etc): */
  min-block-size: 100dvh;
}

main > * {
  /* positioning the children of the <main> element in grid-column 2 (the center
     column of the three-column layout): */
  grid-column: 2;
  /* irrelevant, just to visualise the layout more clearly: */
  outline: 2px solid hsl(0deg 100% 100%);
  /* applying padding to the block and inline axes ('height' and 'width' respectively,
     in European languages and derivatives): */
  padding-block: 0.5em;
  padding-inline: 1em;
}

.inside {
  /* showing the yellow background (though in hsl() form): */
  background-color: hsl(60deg 100% 50%);
}

.full-width3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  /* starting the element in grid-column 1, and setting it's span to 3 (the number of columns): */
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  /* irrelevant, adjust to taste: */
  min-block-size: 3em;
  padding-block: 0.5em;
  padding-inline: 1em;
}

/* a demonstration of "semantic" elements, all of the below content is irrelevant to the
   overall demo however: */
figure {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border: 2px solid hsl(0deg 100% 100%);
  float: inline-end;
  inline-size: 40%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-inline-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 0.5em;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: end;
}
```

```html
<!-- using semantic elements so far as possible, with a <main> element rather than
     a <div> with a class-name: -->
<main>
  <!-- again, trying to use meaningfully semantic elements, though this depends on
       your specific use-case; adjust to whatever element-type you prefer but
       remember to adjust your CSS selectors if necessary: -->
  <section><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, provident. Rerum velit aut dicta repellendus quod soluta natus necessitatibus, sit, nisi corporis quos quaerat voluptatibus voluptate doloribus alias inventore provident porro non quas distinctio fugiat unde nemo. Dolor velit facere libero accusantium aperiam eum excepturi ut nemo, cumque nam recusandae quis quo porro dicta deserunt, dolores a ex voluptatibus. Ratione.</p></section>
  <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati laborum harum omnis dolorem dolores.</section>
  <div class="inside full-width3">full width container</div>
  <section>
    <figure>An inspiring quote ascribed to a likely-famous historical person, almost always against a nature background, to reinforce the desired emotional response.
      <figcaption>An Internet Stranger, 2022</figcaption>
    </figure>
  <p>Yet more "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque quaerat iusto, repudiandae tenetur. A beatae repellendus ut. Facere iste voluptatem, doloremque explicabo animi, magnam iusto consectetur saepe beatae delectus inventore. Quis incidunt cumque dignissimos labore vitae, veniam natus odio quod culpa?" content. Along with Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, perferendis explicabo ad odio officia dolorem excepturi laboriosam! Delectus minus quos soluta, quasi eum excepturi necessitatibus pariatur, exercitationem eius, ex consequatur, fuga a ipsa. Ratione, dolorem. Veritatis autem minima consequatur, rem voluptate suscipit eaque odio omnis tenetur consequuntur deserunt, excepturi quos.</p></section>
</main>
```

JS Fiddle demo.

References:

- [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
- [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [CSS Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/).
- [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).
- [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`font-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style).
- [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-auto-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns).
- [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).
- [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).
- [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-end).
- [`margin-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`margin-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-end).
- [`margin-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start).
- [`min-block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-block-size).
- [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).